# height() not returning correct height on element

Tags: jquery, height, outerheight

I am trying to fix overflowing floating content by adjusting the box height to the overflowed content height but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

```
            if ( $('.content-right').outerHeight() > $('.content-right').parent().parent().height() ) {
                $('.content-right').parent().parent().height($('.content-right').outerHeight(true));
            }
            console.log('Box Height: ' + $('.content-right').parent().parent().height());
            console.log('Content Height: ' + $('.content-right').height() );
```

This will output

```
Box Height: 599
Content Height: 594
```

Which is incorrect as the div is clearly a lot larger in the example below. Any ideas?

[image: Problem Area]
Problem area in image form: http://prntscr.com/4p1obb

Comment: If you read carefully the Docs: http://api.jquery.com/height/ it says clearly: *`This method does not accept any arguments.`*

Comment: Instead of using `.parent().parent()` take a look at the http://api.jquery.com/closest/ method.

Comment: Also, **cache the elements** you plan to use more that once and excessively `var $contRight = $('.content-right');`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That's an error from a edit on here. It was `outerHeight(true)` None of the comments are directed at the issue and nick-picking.

Comment: I cannot know that. I'm just suggesting looking at the code **you** provided. Are you sure you're getting the right element? I see you use `class` selector elements. Might return just the wrong one?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan nothing is cached cause it's been re-written from being cached trying everything to get a solid height out of `.content-right` as seen on the example page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug jQuery outerHeight in older versions where it won't return the height if you don't pass a parameter.  Also as suggested in the comments you need to remove the true from height().

```
if ( $('.content-right').outerHeight(true) > $('.content-right').parent().parent().height() ) {
  $('.content-right').parent().parent().height($('.content-right').outerHeight(true));
}
console.log('Box Height: ' + $('.content-right').parent().parent().height());
console.log('Content Height: ' + $('.content-right').height() );
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this (and the bug mentioned above still applies, so make sure to put in a parameter).  The code below gives me a height of 868.

```
var outerHeight = 0;
$('.content-right > *').each(function() {
  outerHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
});
console.log(outerHeight);
```

Comment: Please cache your selectors! Use `.closest('selector')` method instead of unnecessarily nesting `.parent()`

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan It is not my goal to optimize the OP's code.  I am suggesting an answer to his question.  You have already suggested this in your comments above, so he can do it on his own.

Comment: Roko, quit being biased. It has nothing to do with the functionality. it's personal opinion. As stated it has been re-written FROM vars trying to debug. 

Thank you, as seen on the page, there is no error. The returned height is **not correct**

Comment: @manishie The issue is seen in the image provide. `.content-right` is a lot larger than the returned result: http://prntscr.com/4p1obb